# show this function have this $2f(\sqrt{xy})=f(x)+f(y),\forall x,y>0$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations, means

Let $f:R^{+}\to R$ and such foy any $x,y>0$ have
$$f(\frac{x+y}{2})+f(\frac{2xy}{x+y})=f(x)+f(y)$$
show that
$$2f(\sqrt{xy})=f(x)+f(y),\forall x,y>0$$

I find this result surprising because the arithmetic mean, the geometric mean, the harmonic mean all appear in this function,But I can't prove it,Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Miklos Schweitzer 2001 5: Functional Equation conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150885/miklos-schweitzer-2001-5-functional-equation-conditions) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f(%5Cfrac%7Bx%2By%7D%7B2%7D)%2Bf(%5Cfrac%7B2xy%7D%7Bx%2By%7D)%3Df(x)%2Bf(y)%24&p=1)