# Functional equation $f\left( \dfrac{2xy}{x+y}\right) +f\left( \dfrac{x+y}{2}\right) =f\left( x\right) +f\left( y\right)$

Tags: analysis

I have not any idea, how to attack the equation
$$f\left( \dfrac{2xy}{x+y}\right) +f\left( \dfrac{x+y}{2}\right) =f\left( x\right) +f\left( y\right)$$
with  unknown  $f:\mathbb{R} _{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Allowing (for a while) that $y$ can be equal to $0$, we get
$$\begin{aligned}f\left( \dfrac{x}{2}\right) =f\left( x\right) \\ f\left( \dfrac{x}{2^{n}}\right) =f\left( x\right) \\ f\left( 2x\right) =f\left( x\right) \\ f\left( 2^{n}x\right) =f\left( x\right) \end{aligned}$$

This suggests that f can be constant.
Otherwise, as $$\begin{aligned}HM\left( x,y\right) \cdot AM\left( x,y\right) =GM^{2}\left( x,y\right)= xy,\end{aligned} $$

one can guess that (up to a constant) $f$ can be a logarithmic function.
So, $f(x) =A\ln x+B$.
How to perform a rigorous proof of these ( maybe without guessing ?)
How to prove, that there's not other solutions ?
Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150885)

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(%5Cfrac%7B2xy%7D%7Bx%2By%7D)%2Bf(%5Cfrac%7Bx%2By%7D%7B2%7D)%3Df(x)%2Bf(y)%24&p=1), there are quite a few posts where it's asked that, if the functional equation you specify is true, then we also have $2f(\sqrt{xy})=f(x)+f(y)$. in addition to the related question linked to in [Sil's comment](/questions/4768066/functional-equation-f-left-dfrac2xyxy-right-f-left-dfracxy2-rig#comment10126769_4768066), there's also ...

Comment: (cont.) [Functional equation $f\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)+f\Big(\frac{2xy}{x+y}\Big)= f(x)+f(y)$](/q/380355). There are also quite a few AoPS threads, e.g., [f((x+y)/2) + f(2xy/(x+y)) = f(x) + f(y)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h532655p3046744) (which says the source is "#41 www.imomath.com/index.php?options=342&lmm=0"), [Mikl&oacute;s Schweitzer 2001 Problem 5](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1381932p7665280), [Miklós Schweitzer](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1344152p7312194), ...

Comment: (cont.) [The function equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1520119p9075787), etc. Finally, there's the AoPS thread of [Functional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1914894p13120555) which asks a fairly similar question, except that it's for continuous functions and that $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$.